# UML activity diagram decision without decision node

Tags: android-activity, uml, diagram

Can UML activity diagram have decision without a decision node or is it wrong? I mean, is it required to use the decision node (diamond symbol) to represent conditions?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and +1 for a correct question.

Answer (score 1):

It is legal UML. Only fUML gets formal about how a value flows into a decision for guard conditions to be compared.

Answer (score 1):

### No,

1. in activity diagram you can also use a much more elaborated element: `Conditional Node`  - [is a structured activity node that represents an exclusive choice among some number of alternatives.](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/VPGallery/diagrams/Activity.html#conditionalnodespecification)
2. It also could exist in variant "conditional node with regions".
3. If your decision has the sense of loop, you can use a `Loop Node` instead.
4. Also, as in UML it is allowed to combine elements from different diagrams, you can use Alt or Loop combined fragments from Sequence Diagram elements.
5. You can also use `Sequence Node` in activity diagram and hide the decision inside it.
6. Also, you can always hide the decision in the arithmetic actions. But being acceptable in code, this way is bad in diagrams - you make them for better understanding the subject, not for shortening the code.

Comment: The problem is the conditional//loop/sequence activity nodes are all notated with a dashed round cornered rectangle with the same keyword "structured" at the top, not possible to distinguish them even through the keyword. In the case of the conditional nodes there is at least one clause, but nothing about how to represent them and their content. It is the same for the loop, nothing about how to draw the setup, test and body parts to distinguish them. Is UML dead since end of 2017 ?

Comment: All these nodes are very distinctly separated in the UML standard, look https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF, chap. 16.11.2. Don't mix the really degenerated and limited business language versions of EA and VP and the UML itself. As for EA and VP, they don't even support the absolutely necessary elements of the most base diagram - class diagram. Use Eclipse software or draw UML by drawing tools, and you won't think that UML is dead.

Comment: Of course, it is limited if you try to use it for metathinking, lePus3 is MUCH more powerful for the supercomplicated tasks, but for all usual programming the UML standard is OK. And don't forget that if you use too clever diagrams, you won't find enough clever developers to understand them. Stay simple.

Comment: *look omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF* : I always refer to it, I speak about the representation in a diagram, the norm says say *A StructuredActivityNode is notated with a dashed round cornered rectangle enclosing its keyword «structured» at the top* and that for all 3.

Comment: In fact long time ago when I added activities in [BoUML](https://www.bouml.fr/) I bypassed half of the kind of actions considering them 'useless' because it was a lot of work, for sure this was not a serious way to do. Recently a user indicated an error in [What is the semantics of UML's ReadVariableAction in BoUML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61403771/what-is-the-semantics-of-umls-readvariableaction-in-bouml) so I looked again about actions and looking at to fix the error and add missing actions, and I see again the loop/sequence/conditional => my remark to you

Comment: And the next line is: "No standard notation is defined for ConditionalNodes, LoopNodes or SequenceNodes" no STANDARD, notice that. Nobody forbids You to mark them as you wish. I also think that simply mentioning in the diagram the necessary variable/condition/none element, is not enough, even if it distinguishes these 3 structures. Of course, EA and VP authors HAD to set some special mark for these 3. But they did not.