# UML class diagrams: how to represent the fulfillment of a role by either 1 of X xor 1..* of Y?

Tags: uml

Let's say I have class Foo that has an association to *some thing(s)* that fulfill(s) a role.  This role could be fulfilled by either (strictly) one Bar xor any number of Baz.  Similarly, the role might be fulfilled by either any number or Bar xor any number of Baz (but a mixed collection is intolerable).  Are there reasonable ways to represent these in a class diagram using only associations, classes, and interfaces?  I would (really) like to avoid using OCL or constraint elements.

(The reason I would like to avoid these is because we are generating code from our UML.  We have already implemented generation that handles associations, classes, and interfaces.  Dealing with OCL would be quite the task.  Constraint elements wouldn't be so bad but still quite a lot of work.)

Comment: What do you want the generated code to come out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with the picture below and create several different versions before deciding which one generates best code (junior-40).

The yellow blocks represent necessary "glue code" needed to straighten your example against your other requirements

[image]

Comment: This is fully correct, but kind of inflexible and complicated (too many classes). No additional restrictions (e.g. OCL), that's also true. It would be helpfull to do a small trade-off analysis - is it better to have a simpler and more flexible model with some OCL or more complex and rigid model with no OCL.

Comment: @Aleks until Huliax provides more details about the code generator (what is it capable of right now) it is undecidable which of our answers is more useful so I'll not change mine. In any case I think we have provided sufficient start-up ground for him/her to continue the modeling attempts

Comment: Fully agreed. You should not change it - it answers perfectly the question (upvote). I deliberately gave a "less fitting" solution that is in my opinion more flexible and maybe can be also used.

Comment: Thanks.  This is what I was looking for.  It is annoying to introduce this extra case classes but it does the job.  Our code generators do not handle OCL right now and having them do so would be a big project.  Handling Constraint elements would be easier but would still take time.  We have a large number of builders that do different things with a model based on the desired output artifact.  That means each builder has to know how to interpret the meaning of each UML element that we use in our models so it is helpful to stick with using UML elements that we already deal with in each builder.

Comment: Note though that containment isn't necessary here.  Simple association would do.

Comment: @Huliax in that case check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_UML. It is a UML subset specifically designed to be used by code generators. I have checked it few years ago. At that time there were some 3 implementations of the concept with tools etc. Times had changed and you might find a better more up-to-date and thought-out definition of the "executable UML subset" with implementation questions (like this one) already answered

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  We have developed plugins for a well known UML editor that allow us to produce a number of artifacts (XML schema, web applications, documents, code stubs for various languages, etc.) from a model.  We have implemented a few features that executable UML seems to forego, for instance containment.  We have chosen what is most useful to us and are adding to the set as needed.  It is kind of funny that some group decided that they were going to be the arbiter or what executable UML would be. I know a guy who claims to have implemented code generation for the entire UML metamodel.

Comment: @Huliax for the rest of us it is quite important (not funny) to know what are the standards or at least proposed standards that we can stick to (e.g. what will ES6 contain). For me it is important to know what features in my UML model can I pack into a XMI format and move to a better tool vendor without loss of my work (or just round-trip my XMI). As an example see the question http://stackoverflow.com/a/22601125/2626313 If the argument goes that fUML recommends to use it and we want to enable MDA code generation then we should use it. BTW: which well known UML editor did you mean?

Comment: I mean MagicDraw.  I mean funny as in odd.  I don't think fUML is odd because it is a standard*.  What I found odd was that somebody decided to name their language "Executable UML", as if it were the only one and when it was (if I understand correctly) not based on a standard.  We are using a subset of canonical UML that you can pass around in XMI.  I'll look into fUML more to see if we are within that subset.  We can build a model and then, for instance, generate the code that will spin up a full stack, deployable application.  We have these apps in production environments.

Comment: *note: standards are perfect.  UML is not perfect.  There are biases baked into the standard that make it difficult to express some object oriented constructs that shouldn't be difficult to express. For example, where are class instance variables?

Comment: @Huliax as for the "Executable UML" aka "xUML" I don't recall the roots but it was somehow defined by someone who was the first one, both by writing and presenting a paper and by creating first implementation in the past century. Some traces available here http://ooatool.com/docs/OOAxUML04.pdf So in the beginning there was not a "some group". There were "some smart guys" who coined the term. Similar to how Mike Cohn coined the "user story" and Ivar Jacobson coined the "use case" etc.

Comment: @Huliax from my OOP point of view, class instance variables are variables in the singleton meta-class object instance. No magic. Just 2 different rectangles. At least this is where they were in Smalltalk and in C (before Objective-C came)

Comment: @Huliax MagicDraw is a nice tool and if your team would help the fUML or others specify and prototype how the code generators (should) work it might be nice for the rest of us - the BFUs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55209/discussion-between-huliax-and-xmojmr).

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of something like the following:

[image: XOR between classes]
<sub>(source: [uml-diagrams.org](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams/class-constraint-dashed.png))</sub>

Where Account is your Foo, Person is your Bar, and Corporation is your Baz.

You can then specify multiplicity on each of the two associations: [1] for Bar (Person) and [1..*] for Baz (Corporation).

Comment: UML doesn't allow two association ends with the same name. You can get away with it if you make the association own the property, but that's weird.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating an abstract class **Thing** and derive Bar and Baz from it. It abstract the whole role, can contain some own atts and methods if needed and is quite flexible and extendible.

Now Account has an association only with AccountOwner (role "role", as Jim L. has explained in his comment, a role name must be unique in this context).

Note that this does not eliminate the need of some additional restrictions. For example, all linked "roles" should be of the same type. Sometimes is not easy (or even possible) to remove all restrictions. Otherwise we would make complete systems out of class diagram. I agree though, that as much information as possible should be contained in classes, their taxonomies and features (atts, assocs and methods).

**EXAMPLE:**

[image]

**EXAMPLE 2 (after comments):**

This version overcomes the need to use OCL ant yet keeps the simplicity and flexibility:

[image]

Multiplicities are now also derived and refined for each concrete "role". No OCL needed. :)

Comment: Original question was expressed in terms of "Foo", "Bar" and "Baz" not in terms of "AccountOwner", "Person" and "Corporation". BTW: can you provide little bit "more visual" example of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You add a constraint on the class in OCL:

```
    (self.role->exists(r|r.oclIsType(Bar)) and self.role->notexists(r|r.oclIsType(Baz)) )  or 
(self.role->exists(r|r.oclIsType(Baz)) and self.role->notexists(r|r.oclIsType(Bar)))
```

You can try this out with MDriven Designer.

The reason for introducing OCL (object constraint language) in the UML specification was just this; ability to add constraint not possible or practical to convey with simple cardinality and type information

Comment: Almost three years after the question was asked it is still true that, while our code generators cover a lot of business cases, they do not parse OCL.  Your product looks pretty interesting and as part of a team doing something similar I can really appreciate it.  Alas, we have too much invested in our own generators (i.e. generated apps deployed for customers) to shift to anything else right now.

Answer (score 0):

Could this image help you ? It is extracted from the norm.
[image: xor image]

Comment: Yes that works too though it would require additional to have our code generators handle constraint elements.  The accepted answer solved the problem (almost three years ago...).