# What is the semantics of UML's ReadVariableAction in BoUML?

Tags: uml, action

ReadVariableAction activity action in BoUML allows to choose a class and its attribute and returns the attribute through creation of output pin (see figure below and [BoUML documentation](https://www.bouml.fr/doc/activityaction.html)):
[image]

But what is the semantic of that action? What does ReadVariableAction operation actually return?

According to clause **16.9.3.1 Variable Action** of [The Unified Modeling Language Specification Version 2.5](https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5/About-UML/):

> A VariableAction operates on a statically-specified Variable. The Variable must be one that is defined either by an Activity (see sub clause 15.2) or a StructuredActivityNode (see sub clause 16.11) containing the VariableAction.

Clause 15.2.2 Abstract Syntax below says that Variable subsets *ownedMember*, so the variable should be identifiable by *name*. 
[image]

But BoUML neither allows creation of variables for an activity nor passing a name of a variable to ReadVariableAction.

It seems that I could use ReadVariableAction as shown below
[image]

But it's wrong model from UML's point of view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semantic of the read/write/clear/add/remove variable actions in BoUML is ... wrong !

Clearly I misunderstood that part when I added the activities in BoUML, I didn't read well the norm to understood that concerns variable of the activity or a structured activity node. So by error the 'variable' I allow to choose is an attribute of a class. An other consequence is you cannot define variables for an activity nor structured activity node.

Mea culpa

---

[BoUML 7.10](https://www.bouml.fr/historic.html) is available and fix the problem

Comment: IMHO, 'variable' actions should probably be renamed into Structural Feature Actions and with added  'object' InputPin everything will look fine. And `Read Self Action` would be greatly appreciated  too ))

Comment: @zer0hedge To both correct and stay compatible I can allow variables for activity (structured node), and when reading a model made by version <= 7.9.1 automatically create them in activity/expansion nodes from the current *read/write/clear/add/remove variable actions* from attribute name/multiplicity/type (adding post fix when attribute have same name but different type), also updating dialog box and  *plug-out* API. For me the compatibility between versions is very important, any version is able to read a model made/modified by any previous lower version since the very first in 2005.

Comment: IMHO, if you align semantic of _variable actions_ with UML specification precisely then all previous usages of _variable actions_ need to be modified manually by the authors of models. So in addition to what you proposed I would consider introducing export previous version functionality which would report all elements whose semantic has been changed so the manual intervention is required. For example, all these elements could be marked - marks have red color and can be saved.

Comment: I added an example to the question. Someone could produce such a model and the model needs to be fixed manually (i.e. `Read Self Action` has to be added etc)

Comment: I like BoUML and can use it 'as-is'

Comment: I was thinking about the answer, but you removed the question :-) Since "In UML,
Property is the only kind of StructuralFeature so all of the StructuralFeatures of a Classifier are Properties", I would say "property"

Comment: @zer0hedge yes I removed remarks. As you proposed I will automatically transform wrong *Variable* actions into equivalent *StructuralFeature* actions because this is the best thing to do, and structural feature will be among attribute/relation-end (as wrong variable actions) more port, all owned member of class (the dialog as before ask to select a class then the member of it) ...

Comment: @zer0hedge ...  I will also add missing actions (variable, self, ...) but not *LinkEndData* actions because I do not manage *QualifierValue*, nor *Link* actions because need *LinkEndData*, nor *LinkObject* actions because *CreateLinkObject* need *CreateLink*.

Comment: @zer0hedge [BoUML 7.10](https://www.bouml.fr/historic.html) is available

Comment: And you have changed the icons in top left corner of windows too - you may mention that in release notes!

Comment: @zer0hedge you are right, I forgot because I did long time ago, anyway I do not speak about that kind of little change in historic